# unable to install hhvm on debian (jessie) via apt

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt, debian-jessie, hhvm

I am trying to setup hhvm using the instructions below but I am getting the error copied below.  If it does not work, I will simply clone the git repo and run make but would prefer not to if possible.

**The debian distro is jessie:**

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)
Release:    8.4
Codename:   jessie
```

**instructions for hhvm**

```
wget -O - http://dl.hhvm.com/conf/hhvm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian jessie main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hhvm
```

**error:**

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: issue was due to the fact that the OS was 32 bit and not 64 bit which HHVM requires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was due to the fact that the OS was 32 bit and not 64 bit which HHVM require.  I was able to install hhvm using the steps above when I tried doing so on a 64 bit OS.